# Formation of dolomite

Tags: geochemistry, mineralogy, biogeochemistry

What are the kinetic barriers to dolomite precipitation? Does it precipitate out in solution as quickly as Calcite does?

Comment: It does not precipitate out of solution. AFAIK (and I may be wrong here), it either forms at high pressure and temperature (igneous carbonatites), as a replacement of pre-existing calcite (dolomitisation) or biogenic (some coral precipitate dolomite and related phases)